# Deleting messages in WhatsApp

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I had a lot of private and group conversations over a year through WhatsApp, but all of a sudden the space it takes seems to be on a high. I was able to delete private messages by long-pressing the person's file and deleting the entire conversation, but when I long-press the group chats, I didn't quite find an option to delete the conversation all at once.

Is there any way to delete private messages all at once rather than doing them individually?

Comment: The question is a bit unclear whether they just want to delete all messages from selected group chats only, or they really want to clear all messages entirely. [The existing answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/59514/44325) handles the latter.

Answer (score 1):

Go to WhatsApp settings> Chat Settings> Delete All conversations